# Optimize query to calculate historical summed values pr. date

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I have a table which looks like this:

```
&ItemNo
&LocationId
&MovementDate
MovementWithinDay
Stock -- the field I need to update with sum of MovementWithinDay for all older records for same item
```

As this table contains over 300 million rows it takes very long time to populate the Stock field.  Each row contains the movements within that day and what I need to do is to calculate the stock based on the sum of MovementWithinDay for all records for this item that are older than this record.  This is a one-time-transaction so moving into another structure is an option.  I have used cursor to loop through the records but it was incredibly slow.  Query with summing up all older records for that item for each record was consideribly faster but very slow.

Could anybody give me pointers to do this in the least amount of time?

Comment: I wrked on a simialr problem and described my solution in my blog: [Denormalizing to enforce business rules: Running Totals](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/01/23/denormalizing-to-enforce-business-rules-running-totals.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, from how I've understood your question, you want running sums of `MovementWithinDay` for every `&ItemNo`. I believe you could employ a [recursive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx) [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx) [with](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) [ranking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx) for that, unless you are on SQL Server 2000 or earlier version.

This is how the query might look:

```
WITH ranked AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    rank = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [&ItemNo] ORDER BY MovementWithinDay)
  FROM
),
cumulated AS (
  SELECT
    [&ItemNo],
    [&LocationId],
    [&MovementDate],
    MovementWithinDay,
    Stock = MovementWithinDay,
    rank
  FROM ranked
  WHERE rank = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    r.[&ItemNo],
    r.[&LocationId],
    r.[&MovementDate],
    r.MovementWithinDay,
    Stock = c.Stock + r.MovementWithinDay,
    r.rank
  FROM ranked r
    INNER JOIN cumulated c ON r.[&ItemNo] = c.[&ItemNo] AND r.rank = c.rank + 1
)
SELECT
  [&ItemNo],
  [&LocationId],
  [&MovementDate],
  MovementWithinDay,
  Stock = MovementWithinDay
FROM cumulated
```

Answer (score 1):

There's really no good answer for SQL Server. Other DB systems would allow you to write an Analytic SUM() function over a partition windowed by your date, but SQL server doesn't.

Your best bet is probably a cursor, sad to say. Take a look [at this SQLTeam article.](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/calculating-running-totals)

The problem with a self join is that SQL server is recalculating the running total from all prior rows for *each* row, instead of saving the total and using it to calculate the next row's running total.